# MRU cache realization

Tags: java

As I undestand this is LRU cache realization:

```
// LRU cache -----------------------------------------------------------------
private static final Map cacheLRU = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(MAX, 0.75f, 
        true/*true for access-order, false for insertion-order.*/) {
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > MAX;
    };
});

static void cacheLRUTest(){
    cacheLRU.put ("1", "one");                           // 1
    cacheLRU.put ("2", "two");                           // 2 1
    cacheLRU.put ("3", "three");                         // 3 2 1
    cacheLRU.put ("4", "four");                          // 4 3 2
       if (cacheLRU.get("2") == null) throw new Error();    // 2 4 3
       cacheLRU.put ("5", "five");                          // 5 2 4
       cacheLRU.put ("4", "second four");                   // 4 5 2
       // Verify cache content.
       if (cacheLRU.size() != 3)              throw new Error();
       if (!cacheLRU.get("4").equals("second four")) throw new Error();
       if (!cacheLRU.get("5").equals("five"))        throw new Error();
       if (!cacheLRU.get("2").equals("two"))         throw new Error();
```

}

How can I realize MRU cache algorithm using LinkedHashMap?

UPDATE:

> http://javalandscape.blogspot.com/2009/01/cachingcaching-algorithms-and-caching.html

As I undestand: LRU - If cache is full I need to delete lru item, MRU - ... mru item

Comment: Why would you want to discard the most recently used item?

Comment: Most Recently Used (MRU):

I am most recently used, in contrast to LRU; I remove the most recently used items first. You will ask me why for sure, well let me tell you something when access is unpredictable, and determining the least most recently used entry in the cache system is a high time complexity operation, I am the best choice that’s why. 

I am so common in the database memory caches, whenever a cached record is used; I replace it to the top of stack. And when there is no room the entry on the top of the stack, guess what? I will replace the top most entry with the new entry.

Comment: Speaking of an algorithm in the first person?  I understand the Zen idea of being one with the code, but this is new for me.

Comment: So you are attempt a micro-tuning optimisation of a relatively complex object. (I would be surprised if you could show there is a difference)   The whole point of a cache is to optimise access using a known access behaviour.  If the access behaviour is unknown the most efficient thing to do is to remove the cache.

Comment: the wikipedia article for mru cache lists the access behaviours for which mru is suitable (and gives references).  more generally, no-one expects you to know everything.  but when you don't know something, it's smarter to go and learn about it than continue arguing from a position of ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, my apologies - i didn't even know MRU was a valid hashing scheme, so sorry for my original comment on the question.

anyway, all you need to do to implement one with LinkedHashMap is to store items in the map and, when that number will cross some limit, discard the most recent.  you can do that easily because LinkedHashMap includes a record of the access order.  so you need to do two things:

1. create the LinkedHashMap with the constructor that allows you to specify the ordering mode, and request access order (since you want ordering to reflect access as well as addition).
2. on insertion, when the size is at the limit, find the first key in the list via the iterator over keys, and remove it.